# Whether or not to use elastic-net or LASSO regression to chose variables for a linear regression?

Tags: lasso, linear, poisson-regression, elastic-net

I am doing a linear regression on the relationship between my outcome and several predictor variables. I am looking to find the more significant variables to include in the regression. I already ran a LASSO and elastic net regression. [image: deviance and log lambda chart (top left is LASSO top right is elastic net and bottom left is ridge regression.] Which one is best to use and why? Also, should I use the lambda.min or lambda.se ?

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code to extract non-zero features:

```
tmp_coeffs <- coef(cv.glmnet.fit, s = "lambda.min")
    data.frame(name = tmp_coeffs@Dimnames[[1]][tmp_coeffs@i + 1], coefficient = mp_coeffs@x)
```

Look at the below answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801130/extracting-coefficient-variable-names-from-glmnet-into-a-data-frame

Comment: How does this answer the question? (I don't see that the question can be answered, a different problem.)

Comment: He has three models, Lasso, rigid and elastic net, which one is better? He could extract non-zero features from these models and build the classifier using these features.

Comment: That seems on all fours with: You could use this code to find out which is better, using your own definition of better. The code could be useful, indeed.